# Correcting and unifying peaks in overlay density plot from rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density, density-plot

I am having trouble with comparing multiple densities and in need for help from R masters.

I am comparing timestamp data collected from 7 different time periods (30, 45, 60, 90, 120, 180 and 240mins) in terms of density.
I plotted an overlay KDE graph using ggplot2.

[image]

What I am trying to do in the next step is to match the y-coordinate of each peak to 1 and adjust the rest of the density points accordingly.
So basically I will multiply each KDE function to a constant that makes each peak equal to 1 (and then visualize the adjusted data by plotting the 'matched peak KDE graph').

How can I do this in Rstudio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of hackish, and there may be a cleaner way of doing it. I'm going to use the iris dataset here.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```

First, building the typical density plot:

```
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, colour = Species)) + 
  geom_density()
p
```

[image]

The `ggplot_build()` function allows you to access the plot's internal information.

```
p_build <- ggplot_build(p)
```

Within that that list, there's a `data` object, that houses the mapped coordinates resulting from the `geom_density()` call. I'll grab that.

```
p_mod <- p_build$data[[1]]
```

Then I make the adjustment. First I need to reestablish what groups the colours refer to, and then I re-set for each colour the y value as desired:

```
p_modded <- p_mod %>%
  mutate(Species = case_when(colour == "#F8766D" ~ "setosa",
                             colour == "#00BA38" ~ "versicolor",
                             TRUE ~ "virginica")) %>% 
  group_by(colour) %>% 
  mutate(y = y / max(y)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

And now a new chart. Note that I don't need to use `geom_density()` because the density has already been calculated, so I just need to use `geom_line()` instead.

```
    ggplot(p_modded, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = Species)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing. Just what I needed!
thank you so much for your help.

Just one quick additional question:

so I plotted the matched peak graph just as below, 
[the graph I need help with][1]

where there is one condition (45min) where the first peak is higher than the second one. 
I need the second peaks to be 1.0, 
but since the code seems to have selected the highest y-value, the first peak (of 45min) is matched to 1.
Would there be a way to adjust this so that the second peaks become 1? 
Perhaps by setting the x-range to above -50? 

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmjFn.png

Comment: Instead of `max(y)` as the denominator, you'd have to change to whatever logic makes sense in that case. Maybe I'd create a new variable indicating for each category what the denominator should be.